# Zend framework redirector doesn't work properly

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to develop a site using Zend Framework, but i have a problem:
I have the default controller which shows me a page with a link. That link uses another controller and redirects me to a start page from that controller (i have implemented startAction() in my custom controller, and the start.phtml page in the modules/default/view/scripts/disc directory).The start view contains a table which is populated from a database, and three link: Add, Edit and Delete. For the Add link i use in start.phtml the following code:

```
<p><a href="<?php   echo $this->url ( array ('controller' => 'disc','action' => 'add'));?>">Add</a></p>
```

And for the other two link something like that except the action name. First time when i use one of the links, everything works fine, but when it returns me to the start page all the links don't work anymore. They just keep me in the start page. In my addAction() i do the things i need, and at the end i use the following code to return to start page :

```
$this->_helper->redirector ( 'start' );
```

and when the start page is loaded again the 'Add' link points to the start page and not anymore to the Add page. The same thing happens with the other two links.

Can anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `start` must be its own route. As a result, you need to specify the default route when using the `url` view helper:

In start.phtml, try this:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url(
        array ('controller' => 'disc','action' => 'add'), 'default');
        ?>">Add</a></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now two of my links work fine, except the first one, and i modify all them at the same way. It's very strange. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad that you're problem is solved. Please consider marking this answer as accepted so that anyone who has the same problem can immediately find the answer.

Comment: As I understand it, you mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the "white" check mark to the left of the answer to toggle it to green.

Answer (score 2):

you are attempting to use the short hand version of the action helper [Redirector()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector)

```
$this->_helper->redirector ( 'start' );
```

To avoid confusion with the utility method version (and because I don't know what the exact defaults are) I always use the proper form.

```
//the redirector helper has to many options to comfortably short hand.
//gotoSimple(), gotoUrl() and gotoRoute() are all easy to use.
$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('action' => 'start', 'controller' => 'index')
```

to use the utility method [_redirect()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods), try something like this (it acepts a url):

```
$this->_redirect('/index/start');
```